# Click on a button inside a panel on a website - using Selenium WebDriver with Cucumber Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, xpath, cucumber

I have tried to setup my test to click on a series of buttons in order on a website and it the test gets stuck on the button I have chosen.
The website in question has multiple panels with buttons on each panel, and I feel like the WebDriver doesn't know what button to look for when I input the XPath of the button into my web.yml file.

This test works on other webpages and other elements, just stuck on this specific website.

**Feature file**

When WebAgent click on MainMenuButton

**web.yml file**

SearchPage:

MainMenuButton: //*[@id="div_1_2_1_1"]/div/div/div/div[1]/a

Things I have tried:
Copying XPath of element on webpage
Trying the full XPath of element
Using different Click On methods in feature file

Expected Outcome - Agent to click on specified button when test run
Actual Outcome - Nothing happens on website when agent is asked to click on the button

Console
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.